# Is there a ModeShape Java client that implements the JCR API?

Tags: java, jcr, modeshape

Jackrabbit has a java client that implements the javax.jcr API that lets you interact remotely with the server over DavEx or RMI.

http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html#getRepository(java.lang.String)

Is there a similar one for ModeShape?

Answer (score 1):

No, ModeShape does not currently have an implementation of the JCR API that talks to a remote ModeShape server. It is on the long-term roadmap, though.